# end of file error while handling options from select tag in selenium Webdriver using Ruby

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The following is the code that I am using to select one particular option from a select tag:

```
       select = driver.find_element(:id, "lang")
       wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
       begin
         all_options = wait.until { driver.find_elements(:tag_name => "option") }
       end
       all_options.each do |option|
             if (option.attribute("value")=="11")
                 option.click
             end
       end
```

I am using jruby. When I execute the commands line by line in the IRB, there is no problem. But, when I run the whole code together, it gives me an error of unexpected End-of-File encountered. Why am I getting this error? Why does it work when executed command by command and not when it is executed as a whole? How do I overcome this?

The error is as follows-

```
SyntaxError: (irb):364: syntax error, unexpected end-of-file

from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
SyntaxError: (irb):364: syntax error, unexpected kEND

end
^
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
SyntaxError: (irb):367: syntax error, unexpected end-of-file

from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
NameError: undefined local variable or method `option' for main:Object
from (irb):367:in `evaluate'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
SyntaxError: (irb):368: syntax error, unexpected kEND

end
    ^
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
SyntaxError: (irb):369: syntax error, unexpected kEND

 end
 ^
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1061:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1160:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.7.1/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:\jruby-1.7.1\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: Can you add all your code. You are either missing and `end` or have and extra one.

Comment: When I removed all the =begin....=end comments, it seemed to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many ends:

```
 begin <--- remove this
     all_options = wait.until { driver.find_elements(:tag_name => "option") }
   end <--- remove this
   all_options.each do |option|
         if (option.attribute("value")=="11")
             option.click
         end
   end
```

Or, if you need a rescue:

```
 begin
     all_options = wait.until { driver.find_elements(:tag_name => "option") }
  rescue
     do someting
  end 
   all_options.each do |option|
         if (option.attribute("value")=="11")
             option.click
         end
   end
```